# Django admin: filtering by "now" in list view

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.2

I have a Django Model that implements a time range, like this:

```
class Period(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(_(u'start time'))
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(_(u'end time'))
```

I have a simple ModelAdmin for it as well.  I'd like to provide a filter in the admin list view that buckets these Periods into "future", "in progress", and "past".  I can enable date filters for the start_time and end_time separately and hack up the change_list.html template to provide the proper query string, like this for in progress Periods:

```
<li><a href="?start_time_lte=[now]&end_time_gt=[now]">In Progress</a>
```

My question is, is there any way to provide something for [now] that is evaluated server-side when the QuerySet is run?  I know you can pass callables into a QuerySet filter, but it seems like that functionality isn't available with FilterSpecs.  I hate to have to stuff a datetime string into the query string because I know my admins will bookmark the filtered links and will get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the new [list_filter feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter), because there's less hacking and such.

If you're stuck with Django 1.2, I can't help you.

Comment: Rats, I am indeed stuck on 1.2.  That is exactly what I need though, so it's good to know about.  Thanks!

Comment: If you're truly stuck, you can try finding the patch(es) for the list_filter feature and applying it to your copy of 1.2. Hopefully the patch isn't part of another, larger one and doesn't break any other functionality.